# Prime Factorization using Stacks

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to write a program that uses a stack to print the prime factors of a positive integer in descending order.

However, I'm not sure what I'm doing is exactly on point.

This is the code that I have so far. At the moment I have the prime factorization done, but the `Stack` part is tripping me up.

```
import java.util.Stack; // Initialize Stacks

public class PrimeFactorization {

    public static void printPrimeNumbers(int prime) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); //create stack
        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //intialize for loop to check each letter
            stack.push(n);
        }

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            n += stack.pop();
        }

        for (int i=0; i <= prime; i++) {
            n = 0;
            while (prime % i == 0) {
                prime /= i;
                n++;
            }

            if (n != 0) {
                for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    if (prime != 1) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPrimeNumbers(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: @partycoder A stack will work here since the goal is to print prime factors in descending order....

Answer (score 2):

You can do basically find the prime numbers and add them to stack then just print until there is no element on stack:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printPrimeFactors(189); // prints 7 3 3 3
}

public static void findPrimeNumbers(int n, Stack<Integer> stack) {

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            stack.add(i);
            n /= i;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

public static void printPrimeFactors(int n){
    if(n > 1){
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        findPrimeNumbers(n, stack);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(stack.pop()+ " ");             
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find all the 2's which divide the input and add them to `stack`.

Second, find all prime numbers greater than 2 and if they divide input, add them to `stack`.

Third, as a last step, check whether the input itself is a prime number greater than 2. If so, print it since step 2 will not add that number.

```
 public static void printPrimeNumbers(int n) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); //create stack

    //First Step
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        stack.add(2);
        n = n / 2;
    }

    //Second Step
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            stack.add(i);
            n = n / i;
        }
    }

    //Third Step
    if (n > 2) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", n);
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", stack.pop());
    }
}
```